# 売買の買とbuyの関係はあります？

Tags: etymology, onyomi, comparative-linguistics

買 in 売買{ばいばい} is pronounced ばい. The word "to buy", which is the translation of 買う, sounds the same. Is there some sort of connection?! 親父ギャグだけなのか…？

Comment: Are you asking whether the *on-yomi* 買【ばい】 and English "to buy" are related?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ないです。

It's only a superficial coincidence in present-day pronunciation.

The word corresponds to English *buy* is assumed to have been pronounced like [**bugjaną*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/bugjan%C4%85) //buɣ.jɑ.nɑ̃// in Proto-Germanic period [around 500 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language#Archaeology_and_early_historiography). Meanwhile, 買 is assumed to have been pronounced like **mˁrajʔ* ([Baxter-Sagart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Baxter-Sagart_Old_Chinese_reconstruction)) or **mreːʔ* ([Zhengzhang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B2%B7#Chinese)) in the Central Plain of China. It still retains *m-* consonant in most Sinitic languages (dialects).

The reason why we have *b-* for this kanji is that, Buddhist monks imported Middle Chinese vocabulary through Chang'an (the capital of Tang) dialect, which showed denasalization making *m-* into *mb-*; they transcribed it with then-prenasalized consonant *<sup>n</sup>b-*, which corresponds to today's voiced *b-*.

Answer (score 5):

From [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=buy)

> **buy** (v.)
>
> Old English *bycgan* (past tense *bohte*) "to buy, pay for, acquire; redeem, ransom; procure; get done," from Proto-Germanic **bugjan* (source also of Old Saxon *buggjan*, Old Norse *byggja*, Gothic *bugjan*), which is of unknown origin and not found outside Germanic.
>
> The surviving spelling is southwest England dialect; the word was generally pronounced in Old English and Middle English with a -dg- sound as "budge," or "bidge." Meaning "believe, accept as true" first recorded 1926. Related: Bought; buying. To buy time "prevent further deterioration but make no improvement" is attested from 1946.

From 新漢和大辞典

> #### 【買】
>
> [常用音訓] **バイ**・**か**う
> [音] バイ（漢）・メ（呉）
> mĕg – măi (mbăi) – mai – mai (mǎi)

Only looking at the development of these two words in themselves, it seems to be very unlikely that there is any connection between 買【ばい】 and "to buy".