# Is the pronunciation of 翼 (tsubasa) 訓読み or 音読み?

Tags: etymology

I noticed that the first two syllables of the pronunciation of 翼 is tsuba, which sounds very similar to Chinese word 翅膀(chibang). 翅膀 is the colloquial form of 翼 in Chinese. Is this a coincidence? Or it's that when this word was borrowed from Chinese, the writing of 翼 while the pronunciation of 翅膀 was imported?

Comment: A spiritual sequel of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40856/7810 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question directly,「[翼]{つばさ}」is a *kun'yomi*.

There is no proposed link between **つばさ** and Mandarin **chìbǎng**.

- The academic attempt to derive the most ancient etymology for **つばさ** can be found in [The Tower of Babel](http://starling.rinet.ru/), where in their [Japanese Etymology](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/query.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Calt%5Cjapet) database there is a proposal that it is derived from a [Proto-Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japonic_languages) root **/*tumpasa/**, and cognate to a Mongolian word **ǯiber**. As far as I know, there is no proposal that **つばさ** is a compound of other morphemes.
- 「翅膀」is a compound comprised of「翅」and「膀」.「翅」([Old Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese): **/*s-kʰe-s/**) is of unknown origin, with variants「翨」and「」in old texts used largely as family names, but also sometimes used as a phonetic substitute for「啻」(also in old texts).「膀」just means *shoulder*.

---

Even if there was a link, having a Chinese-derived pronunciation does not mean that something is *on'yomi*. *On'yomi* are [constructed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanqie) or derived from systematic pronunciations of Chinese characters as recorded in [rime dictionaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rime_dictionary), and Chinese-originated pronunciations which are not based on these phonological references are not actually *on'yomi*. Examples:

- [麻婆豆腐]{まーぼーど​ーふ} - the reading for this word is *irregular*, derived straight from Modern Mandarin. Apart from「腐」, the individual characters do not correspond to the *on'yomi* of the characters, although they are *very close*; an *on'yomi* reading would look like [麻婆豆腐]{まばとうふ}.
- [梅]{うめ} - A *kun'yomi*, believed to come from Middle Chinese, according to [*Daijirin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daijirin) and [*Daijisen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daijisen). The proposed evolution is: [Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese) **/muʌi/**, [Old Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese) ***/mme/** (written as **むめ**), [Heian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian_period) pronunciation **mume2** freely changing into **ume**, then finally settling to the modern pronunciation **ume**.
- [茗]{ちゃ} - A *kun'yomi*, derived from the *on'yomi* of「茶」.

Comment: Starostin is interesting, but his connections can be ... dodgy, at times.  I cannot find any Mongolian term [жибэр (_ǯiber_)](http://www.bolor-toli.com/dictionary/word?search=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%8D%D1%80), for instance.  The closest I can find is [живэр (_ǯiver_)](http://www.bolor-toli.com/dictionary/word?search=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8D%D1%80), which apparently means "moustache".  If [Wiktionary's etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8D%D1%80) is to be believed, this term is a compound, rendering any direct connection to Proto-Japanese **/*tumpasa/** unlikely.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi yep, I was cautious to not put too much weight on the connection. I know the Altaic hypothesis itself is very controversial, and I also couldn't find this word **ǯiber** when I tried, but I supposed that the word being provided in Khalkha (ǯiver), Buriat (žeber), and Kalmuck (ǯiwṛ) meant that **ǯiber** is just something that went out of fashion in Modern Mongolian.

Comment: Very confusing then that Starostin should include that line stating, "**Mongolian**: *ǯiber".  I don't know how else to interpret that but that Starostin believes there is such a term in Mongolian; the other Mongolic terms clearly don't have the same spellings.  Clicking through, it looks like Starostin cites the Mongolian to a [1960 Mongolian-English dictionary](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?&single=1&root=config&basename=/data/biblio/biblio.dbf&text_recno=155).